# The reference for adjectives and meaning

Tags: meaning

I have two questions about the following paragraph:

> The story does not unfold in chronological time. The film begins
> during Marcello’s honeymoon in Paris. It will travel back to visualize
> his enlistment in the secret police, his courtship with Guilia, and
> even further back to the traumatic experiences of his young life. The
> film’s timeline also revisits occasions in which Marcello is called on
> to provide care for his upscale mother, **doped**, **living alone**, and
> **complicit** when taken advantage of by her chauffeur.

1. Is Marcello the reference of "doped, living alone and complicit" or his mother?
2. What does mean "complicit" in this context? There is no crime here.

Comment: What is the source? And none of the dictionaries I've consulted restrict "complicit" just to crimes (although taking advantage of an old lady might be a crime in some circumstances).

Comment: Seems to say that his mother was doped and alone, and complicit in whatever the chauffeur was doing - abuse or embezzlement?

Comment: It could be that no crime was involved, but Marcello's mother was morally culpable, not opposing (within reasonable limits) the chauffeur's obviously sinful/unethical behaviour. 'All that is necessary for evil to triumph is that ...'. See [Mellema: Legal versus Moral Complicity](https://www.aijcrnet.com/journals/Vol_1_No_2_September_2011/16.pdf). But that's speculation. // The paragraph would benefit from having a more explicit clause rather than the string of postpositive (or absolute?) adjectives.